# How to retrieve data from firebase to google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve latitude and longitude data from firebase to my google map, but when I run the application the marker won't show.

Here's my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private FirebaseDatabase tracker;
    private DatabaseReference databaseLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        tracker = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseLocation = tracker.getReference("lokasi3");

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        databaseLocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("lokasi3").getChildren()) {
                    Lokasi3 lokasi3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Lokasi3.class);
                    String latitude = child.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                    String longitude = child.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                    double loclatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double loclongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    LatLng cod = new LatLng(loclatitude, loclongitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(""));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen to your data in onCreate

```
 databaseLocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("lokasi3").getChildren()) {
            Lokasi3 lokasi3 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Lokasi3.class);
            String latitude = child.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
            String longitude = child.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
            double loclatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            double loclongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            LatLng cod = new LatLng(loclatitude, loclongitude);
            googleMap1.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(""));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }


});





GoogleMap googleMap1;//make it global

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap1=googleMap;

}
```

Comment: hi, bro. i try your suggestion to place it in onCreate, but the marker still won't show

Comment: marker1=gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng
                            (dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(double.class),
                                    dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(double.class)))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)).title("Bus 1"));
                    marker1.showInfoWindow();    ---this is working for me.

Comment: sorry for late reply, my internet down so long. so where do you put it in? isi it onDataChange?