# How else can you make a variable in a class with Google Maps not a null?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a class with map, and took coordinates and `title`, from `Firebase` in `String` format, then put them into `double`, but can't place them to new `LatLng`? I understand, that problem is that `googleMap = null`, but re-tried all the ways to solve it. In this version of code, `nullexception` is disapearing, but `marker` is empty. Help please. It the last problem of my app..

```
public class Map_activity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_activity);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("qwerty");
        String xlat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
        String xlon = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lon");
        xlat.split(",");
        xlon.split(",");
        String [] latlong = {xlat, xlon};
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
        if (googleMap != null){
        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(value));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));}           
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate` is getting called before `onMapReady`. If the map is not ready, then the only value `googleMap` can be is `null`.

The only solution is to move the code that needs `googleMap` out of `onCreate` and put it somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try this @user234461. The reason, that i put it in OnCreate, that i ssw an answere with similar problem, and this was solution, but not for me.

Comment: could you link to that answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545527/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-google-map @user234461, earlier it seemed to me that our problems are similar

Comment: Big thanks my dear @user234461, you make my day!

Comment: The reason that the answer you linked to doesn't suffer from the same problem is that instead of running the code involving `googleMap` immediately, it creates an event listener which runs the code later (`onDataChange`). However, this assumes that the map will be ready before the data change happens, which is not necessarily true and could cause bugs. So the code in that answer is potentially buggy.

Comment: I will keep in mind, thanks again for the help@user234461